# CryptoJS.SHA3 in code behind in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sha, cryptojs

Now I am using below code in aspx page. But Now I need something in code behind in C#. Is there any library available?

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha3.js"/>
<script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("Message", { outputLength: 512 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are libraries that implement SHA3 in C#. Some are:

- [Hashlib](https://hashlib.codeplex.com/)
- [SHA3Net](https://github.com/drewjcooper/SHA3Net)
- [SHA3 0.9.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SHA3/)

Checkout their docs for code examples.

Comment: Will I get same hash value which I am getting JAVASCRipt?

Comment: In theory, you should, given all conditions are identical.

Comment: Source of SHA3 0.9.2: https://github.com/ststeiger/SHA-3. Also, BouncyCastle has SHA3-support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211926/bouncy-castle-sha3-wrong-output